# How to determine which attribute an AttributeError refers to?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, standard-library, anti-patterns

When I ask for an attribute of a python object that does not exist, I get an AttributeError, however I have not found the name of the requested attribute among the fields of the error object. The only place which mentions the name of the requested attribute is `args` member of the error.

It seems to me a bit of an annoyance to parse the error message in order to get the name of the missing attribute. Is there any way to get the name of the missing attribute without parsing the error message?

Demo:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print('in A')


class B:
    pass


class C:
    def f(self):
        print('in C')
        raise AttributeError()


def call_f(o):
    try:
        o.f()
    except AttributeError as e:
        # instead of e.args[0].endswith("'f'") it would be nice to do
        # e.missing_attribute == 'f'
        if e.args and e.args[0].endswith("'f'"):
            print(e.args) # prints ("'B' object has no attribute 'f'",)
        else: raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()
    c = C()

    call_f(a)
    call_f(b)
    call_f(c)
```

Comment: No, there isn't. Why don't you know what attribute you're trying to access? Even if you're doing it dynamically with e.g. `getattr`, you have the `name` parameter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What I would like to do is to suppress the error if `hi` is not defined in `a`. On the other hand, if `hi` _is_ defined in a, then it might raise AttributeError inside, and in this case I would like to propagate this error further (re-raise in my except block).

Comment: If it's defined, there won't *be* an error. Could to give a concrete use case?

Comment: @jonrsharpe If it `hi` is defined _and_ it throws AttributeError itself (in it's body), then there is no way to distinguish between whether AttributeError is due to the absence of `hi` or due to the absence of something else that was required from within `hi`. I need to parse the error message in the error to understand it. Here's a demo: http://pastebin.com/wxss4b8XThe

Comment: I meant the problem you were actually trying to solve, not something so contrived. But you've got an answer you like, so never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no uniform way to do that currently. The feature has been suggested in [PEP 473](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0473/#attributeerror)
which is still in draft form

Comment: @anton you have, it says *"`AttributeError` : target , attribute"*